# Simon Listens 4.0 build error

Tags: cmake, simon

When trying to install Simon Listens 4.0, I get this error message:

```
sudo ./build_ubuntu.sh CMake  
Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:98  
(MESSAGE): ERROR: cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake not found in /home/me/.kde/share/apps;/usr/share/kde4/apps  
Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Could someone please tell me how to fix this. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

The `FindKDE4Internal.cmake` file is in the `kdelibs5-dev` package. Just install that and you should be go.

Comment: Well I install that and libqwt-dev. Because It needs it. but now I have a new error.
'CMake Error at /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:198 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find ALSA (missing: ALSA_LIBRARY ALSA_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/FindALSA.cmake:82 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)'
I don't know what ALSA lib. it need.

Comment: Try installing `libasound2-dev`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install libasound2 with  `sudo apt-get install libasound2` package.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to install libasound2-dev: `sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev`

Comment: Why do think this will help in this case? Judging from the error message it seems very unlikely that a missing libasound2-dev is the problem here.

Answer (score -1):

This command can workout the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-runtime-dev kde-workspace-dev
```