# simon listens 4.0 build - further - error

Tags: installation, speech-recognition, simon

I'm a PhD researcher in Applied Anthropology, and I am trying to dictate fieldnotes to my Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (x86_64 3.2.0-36-generic). I undestand Simon is a "[simple install-and-go project](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5495/speech-recognition-api)" which fits my unix basic skill level.

Installing Simon, I followed instructions on these two other Questions [Unable to install Simon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235008/unable-to-install-simon) and [Simon Listens 4.0 build error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235907/simon-listens-4-0-build-error), thanks to all of you there!

I couldn't solve the problem "The following packages have unmet dependencies: simon : Depends: libattica0 but it is not installable", so I started compiling from the source using "build_ubuntu.sh" script, as suggested by Takakt in the first Question above. (first time for me compiling). 
Then I encountered all the problems told by Matthiew and Xiao-Long Chen in the second Question above. So I installed a lot of libraries.

I still have this error: anyone can help me, please? Thanks so much!

```
./build_ubuntu.sh 
-- Found Qt-Version 4.8.1 (using /usr/bin/qmake)
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Found KDE 4.8 include dir: /usr/include
-- Found KDE 4.8 library dir: /usr/lib
-- Found the KDE4 kconfig_compiler preprocessor: /usr/bin/kconfig_compiler
-- Found automoc4: /usr/bin/automoc4
-- Found Qt-Version 4.8.1 (using /usr/bin/qmake)
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Found Qwt: /usr/lib/libqwt.so
CMake Warning at /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/MacroOptionalFindPackage.cmake:32     (find_package):
  Could not find module FindQAccessibilityClient.cmake or a configuration
  file for package QAccessibilityClient.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindQAccessibilityClient.cmake or set
  QAccessibilityClient_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for QAccessibilityClient.  The file will have one of the following
  names:

    QAccessibilityClientConfig.cmake
    qaccessibilityclient-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (macro_optional_find_package)


-- Found SphinxBase 
-- WARNING: OpenCV was not found. Please specify OpenCV directory using OpenCV_DIR     env. variable
-- BackendType='both'

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- The following external packages were located on your system.
-- This installation will have the extra features provided by these packages.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * KDE PIM Libs - KDE Libraries for PIM
   * Sphinxbase - Open source toolkit for speech recognition
   * PocketSphinx - PocketSphinx is a small-footprint continuous speech recognition     system

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- The following OPTIONAL packages could NOT be located on your system.
-- Consider installing them to enable more features from this software.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * LibSampleRate  <http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/>
     Resampling library
     Required to activate resampling.
   * qaccessibilityclient      <https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/accessibility/libkdeaccessibilityclient>
     KDE client-side accessibility library
     Required to enable ATSPI plugin.
   * OpenCV  <http://http://opencv.willowgarage.com/>
     OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision) is a library of programming functions for     real time computer vision
     Required for Simon Vision

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to     NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
X11_XTest_LIB (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "eventsimulation" in directory /home/miro/Downloads/simon-    0.4.0/simonlib/eventsimulation

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: We built Simon on Raspbian (Raspberry Pi) (Was a bad idea anyway). This should help you out too.

*QAccessibilityClientConfig.cmake
qaccessibilityclient-config.cmake*

```
aptitiude install libqaccessibilityclient0 libaccessibility-dev
```

*WARNING: OpenCV was not found. Please specify OpenCV directory using OpenCV_DIR*

```
aptitude install libopencv-dev
```

*LibSampleRate  http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/*

```
aptitude install libsamplerate0-dev
```

You will also need:

```
aptitude install libboost-dev
```

I also needed the following packages to compile successfully:

```
aptitude install libasound2-dev libxtst-dev 
aptitude install bison
aptitude install libqwt6 libqwt-dev
aptitude install kdepimlibs5-dev kdepimlibs
```

It seems that `Pocketsphinx` and `Sphinxbase` are allready on your system. But you will also need `Sphinxtrain`. You will need to compile it from source (**Note**: they have to be in the same directory). Get it here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/

or try the HTK Speech Modul

http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/download.shtml

Those who try to compile Simon on a armhf Based Platform will get the error message:

*error: no matching function for call to 'qBound(double, qreal, qreal)'*

replace the doubles to float **around** line 222 in qwt_bars_item.cpp, and line 65 qwt_bars_item.h

```
/tmp/simon/sam/src/qwt_bars_item.cpp:222
/tmp/simon/sam/src/qwt_bars_item.h:65
```

Those steps should result in a successful build of Simon.

To use Simon, make sure you have [Julius](http://julius.sourceforge.jp/en_index.php) and [libqt4-sql-sqlite](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqt4-sql-sqlite) installed.

Comment: Wow, I still have much to do! Thanks JohannesM, very much.
`aptitude install libqaccessibilityclient libaccessibility-dev` gives me the following error: 
`Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libqaccessibilityclient"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libaccessibility-dev"`

Comment: it's `ibqaccessibilityclient0`. I've missed the zero.

Comment: Actually I missed it but still `Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libqaccessibilityClient0"`

Comment: Instead of `libqaccessibilityclient0` on 12.04, I had to install `kaccessible`. That resolved my issue. Well, that plus doing all of the other stuff that JohannesM suggested above. :)

Answer (score 1):

Following answer from JohannesM :

The correct spelling for the two packages are :
`libqaccessibilityclient0` and `libqaccessibilityclient-dev` but they are not in default repositories for 12.04. You can find them on there :

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/kubuntu-ppa_backports/precise/main/base/libqaccessibilityclient0

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/kubuntu-ppa_beta/precise/main/base/libqaccessibilityclient-dev
for example.

`libxtst-dev` should also be installed to avoid the error with X11_XTest_LIB